# Line numbers for listings using program package

Tags: line-numbering, program

Is it possible to add line numbers to listings using the `program`package?

(I know, that it should be possible within the much more sophisticated other listings packages available, but I would really rather stick to to `program`, as I am used to the pseudocode syntax now and I like the style of the result, which did not require a plethora of options to make it look "nice").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can toggle line numbering by issuing

```
\NumberProgramstrue
```

for getting line numbers or

```
\NumberProgramsfalse
```

for switching off numbering. The setting is local to an environment, but the commands should be *outside* a `program` environment.

If you want to modify the style, change the definition of `\prognumstyle`; the default is

```
\newcommand{\prognumstyle}{\scriptsize\em}
```

so, if you want the numbers upright, just say in the preamble (after `\usepackage{program}`, of course)

```
\renewcommand{\prognumstyle}{\scriptsize}
```

Comment: Great, that works. Thank you. Especially for the style hint, as that would have been my next question anyways!

Comment: @qqilihq I suspected that, after seeing the italic parentheses and numbers.